# Theoretical and practical categorization of camera switches: categorization and implementation: techniques and strategies

Tags: accessibility, camera-switches

This post has some overlapping with UX, so I could have posted it on the UX stack exchange, but I wanted to make it specific, to, camera switch support, in Android. That is why I have posted it here. Camera switches are an accessibility feature, that allow, people, disabled or not, to control the phone via face movements and gestures. An example of this, is ALS (amiotrophic lateral sclerosis), and/or where the body has undergone paralysis, and only the eyes, and, perhaps, other parts of the face, as can vary with medical condition and physical physiology, and as may also be affected by medication, are available.

The system, should, allow, the user, to configure which switches they want to have configured or want configured.

....

Switch access could present a list of switches you wanted to try to configure.

It, could, present, an animated, video info graphics animation, to show what the switch was.

The switch could involve a configure and hold, functionality.

The switch could involve a transitory, gesture, functionality (more or less, something, moves, and then goes back into place).

The switch could involve a head movement. In this case, position, speed, and acceleration, parameters, as the head traces a path on the the polar coordinates sphere, must, be manageable

By granularity

By gesture shape

.

So, for example, you could configure a head path.

....

Do we need a website where people can list their camera switches, as pictures, and names, alongside their medical condition, or disability (perhaps, even listing, medication, they take)?

This way people working with camera switches can make decisions, based, on, what the switches are, or could be.

For example, one person could have a mouth muscle to allow a distinction between smile a little and smile a lot. Or, they could have muscles to allow nostril flaring (they, may even, have been able to train the muscles). Other people, may, have, other, possible camera switches, at their disposal.

But, if we cannot learn, what these are (or may be), then we cannot program, cater, and support them.

Thank you.

The question is, how can we cater to more camera switches uses, users, and use cases. With regards to what has been written in this post, what can we do, what can be done, or how can we improve and implement what has been written here? Has, anyone, been working on this?

Thanks.

Comment: Reminder, that requests for features (we are not Google or any third-party app developer) and speculative type questions ("When will...", "Do we need...") is considered [off-topic](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). While the goal of the post may be admirable, Android Exchange isn't the right forum for such a topic/set of open-ended questions. Take a look at [Where can I ask questions that aren't Android Enthusiast questions?](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/371/3573) for a more appropriate forum.